# cannot convert value of type 'String' to type 'NSString' in coercion when i use self swift2 with ubuntu 16.04

Tags: swift, ubuntu

i have a problem with a code that throw the next message:

```
error: cannot convert value of type 'String' to type 'NSString' in coercion
            return (self as NSString).substringWithRange(range)
```

I could resolve it before but not with a self calling, so here is the code:

```
let range = expression.rangeOfFirstMatchInString(self, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, self.utf16.count))
    if range.location != NSNotFound {
        return (self as NSString).substringWithRange(range)
    }
    return nil
```

Comment: Try `return NSString(string: self)...`

Comment: yes, it worked, thanks :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The swift compiler in Ubuntu won't auto recognize that `NSString` has a constructor that gets `String` as argument. (at build time the compiler interprets it)

Instead do the work by your self by writing

```
NSString(string: self)
```